# Anime where a boy needs the power of the Shinigami and befriends one who looks like a white and red bunny

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is gonna be very obscure. There is a exorcist or priest or something and he's a teen. His dad retires and its his turn to take over. But he needs the power of the Shinigami (don't know how to describe them). He builds trust with them and one in particular who looks kinda like a white and red bunny I believe and is very stubborn and does not like the boy. They finally grow to trust in each other but then the boy gets in danger and the Shinigami uses his power to save him (or vice versa, can't remember) and the Shinigami loses its memory and they have to start over.

Comment: Is the bunny actually related in some way to death, or are you thinking of a *shi**k**igami*? "Exorcist" could have been used to translate *onmyouji*, and those tend to go hand in hand.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinigami

Comment: The Blue Exorcists The main charcter owns a sword that is used to seal the demons, but the 'good deamons' are recurring theme in anime, some of them being the protagonist allies. The movie has theme of a good bunny demon who can erase memories. Not a very good match, but for the sake  of crosing it out of the list I leave it here. I also seems to remember an opening from an Alice in Wonderland inspired anime, that featured a red-white rabbbit character that looks like sewn from two differently colored halves. This may be a lead if that kind of visuals rings a bell.